# SQL - exclude multiple rows if one of the rows meets the condition

Tags: sql, multiple-records

How do you exclude multiple rows if one of the rows meets the condition?

```html
<table>
  <th>Instruction_ID</th>
  <th>Instruction_Desc</th>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Please use these products:</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Kerlix</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Sodium Chloride</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Tegaderm</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Please use these products</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Sodium Chloride</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to exclude all rows for a given instruction_id if one of the rows in the group has the word "Kerlix."  The desired output would be:

```html
<table>
  <th>Instruction_ID</th>
  <th>Instruction_Desc</th>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Please use these products</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Sodium Chloride</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you keep editing your question?  You have 2 posted solutions that both work.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Here's one using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Instruction_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Instruction_ID
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Comments LIKE '%Kerlix%'
)
```

And here's one using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE Comments LIKE '%Kerlix%' AND t1.Instruction_Id = t2.Instruction_Id
)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89329/1)

Comment: would `SELECT distinct Instruction_ID` help?

Comment: @Beth -- um, how?  Not sure I'm understanding your comment. I don't see any reason to add the additional overhead of `distinct` in this case.

Comment: that's what I was wondering, if adding the `distinct` clause would improve performance.  You're saying it wouldn't?  That the work done by `distinct` takes longer than joining duplicate values?

Comment: @Beth -- correct, in this case, `distinct` would only add to the overhead of the query.  Perhaps this is what you were thinking of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201885/how-to-determine-what-is-more-effective-distinct-or-where-exists

Answer (score 3):

You can do `self join` AND use `left join`

```
SELECT T1.Instruction_ID, T1.Comments
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table1 T2
ON T1.Instruction_Id = T2.Instruction_Id
and T2.Comments LIKE '%Kerlix%'
WHERE T2.Instruction_Id is NULL
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ce605/4)