# Results from query as argument for WHERE statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: orders and orderProducts. They both have a column called 'order_id'.

orders has a column named 'date_created'
ordersProducts has a column named 'SKU'

I want to SELECT SKUs in within a date range.

My query so far is:

```
SELECT `SKU`
FROM `orderProducts`
INNER JOIN orders
ON orderproducts.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE orders.order_id in (SELECT id FROM orders WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2015-03-31' ORDER BY date_created DESC)
```

The query runs but it returns nothings. What am I missing here?

Comment: In this case you should use the date condition directly in the where clause and get rid of the sub query, but when you do need a subquery, the first step of debuging will be to try each query separatly and only when you get them to work combine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `date` condition in the `where` clause, there is no need for the subquery:

```
select op.`SKU`
from `orderProducts` op
join `orders` o using(`order_id`)
where o.`date_created` between '2014-10-01' and '2015-03-31'
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing the question a bit, what is the correct way if I need to join another table (so three in total)? I'll edit my original question with the  code I got now.

Comment: @iamfbpt : Instead of editing a post with another question better post a new question, as editing the question in the same post invalidates the answers that were already given.

Comment: Deleted the edit and posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911906/joining-three-tables-on-mysql

Answer (score 1):

try using between **clause** in your **where** condition for date, there is no need to use subquery.

```
SELECT `SKU`
FROM `orderProducts`
INNER JOIN orders 
ON orderproducts.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE  date_created BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2015-03-31' ORDER BY date_created DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for this.  Here's one I prefer using `exists`:

```
select sku
from orderproducts op
where exists (
    select 1
    from orders o 
    where o.orderid = op.orderid
        and o.datecreated between '2014-10-01' and '2015-03-31')
```

When using a `join`, you may need to use `distinct` to eliminate duplicates.  Alternatively, you could achieve the same results with `in`, but `exists` should perform better.

Comment: in MySQL `left join/is not null` pattern should give the best performance.

Comment: @notulysses -- that's true against `not exists` -- but `exists` should out perform `distinct/inner join`...  Good post -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201885/how-to-determine-what-is-more-effective-distinct-or-where-exists

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.