# Tip on joining three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to join a few tables as I'll need values that are within all of them.

I've tried two ways so far:

First way:

```
SELECT
    o.`order_id` as `Order ID`,
    o.`STATUS` as `Order Status`,
    o.`date_created` as `Date Created`,
    op.`SKU`,
    op.`NAME`,
    o.`STATE`,
    op.`QUANTITY`,
    c.`customer_id`
FROM
    `orderProducts` op
INNER JOIN
    orders o on op.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN
    customers c on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE
    o.order_id IN (616898, 616901)
```

Second way:

```
SELECT
    o.`order_id` as `Order ID`,
    o.`STATUS` as `Order Status`,
    o.`date_created` as `Date Created`,
    op.`SKU`,
    op.`NAME`,
    o.`STATE`,
    op.`QUANTITY`,
    c.`customer_id`
FROM
    `orders` o,
    `orderproducts` op,
    `customers` c
WHERE
    o.order_id IN (616898, 616901)
AND
    c.customer_id= o.customer_id
AND
    o.order_id = op.order_id
```

Tables data:

orders

```
+----------------------------+------------+------+-----+
| Field                      | Type       | Null | Key |
+----------------------------+------------+------+-----+
| order_id                   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI |
| customer_id                | int(11)    | YES  |     |
```

orderproducts

```
+----------------------------+------------+------+-----+
| Field                      | Type       | Null | Key |
+----------------------------+------------+------+-----+
| order_id                   | int(11)    | NO   |     |
```

customers

```
+----------------------------+------------+------+-----+
| Field                      | Type       | Null | Key |
+----------------------------+------------+------+-----+
| customer_id                | int(11)    | NO   | PRI |
```

Sorry, but I don't really know how to represent the data I want out, I'll try my best to explain it.

I want the columns in my select statement, from the orders 616898 and 616901.
The order_id field is the same in both the order and orderproducts tables. The customer_id field is the same in both the order and customers tables. It's like I'm adding extra columns SKU, NAME, QUANTITY from orderproducts table using the order_id to extract the correct ones and the column email, using the customer_id from the orders and the customers table.

Comment: Add sample data, expected result and the result you get.

Comment: can you please provide Sample table data and your Expected output?

Comment: Will do, just a few minutes.

Comment: i think the problem is with c.email = o.email condition. Can you please tell me more about that?? Why you added that condition?

Comment: I was using email instead of customer_id to check for equality, I corrected it now.

Comment: Your second way is deprecated. ANSI SQL supports explicit joins for over 20 years now, so there really is no need to keep working the old fashion way.

Comment: Why is order_id the primary key for table orderproducts???

Comment: New style (explicit) joins, and old style (implicit) joins. Both ways are valid ANSI SQL, but my recommendation is to always write new style JOINs. They are easier to write, easier to read, and much easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Error while copy pasting hehe. thanks for poiting it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `orders` and `customer` with `customer_id` and its always better to do joining using ids.

So the query would be

```
SELECT
    o.`order_id` as `Order ID`,
    o.`STATUS` as `Order Status`,
    o.`date_created` as `Date Created`,
    op.`SKU`,
    op.`NAME`,
    o.`STATE`,
    op.`QUANTITY`,
    c.`email`
FROM
    `orders` o
INNER JOIN
    orderProducts op on op.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN
    customers c on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE
    o.order_id IN (616898, 616901)
```

Now what this will do

- It will try joining all the tables if there is a matching data i.e. if the same `order_id` is on `orders` and in `orderproducts` and same `customer_id` is in `orders` and `customers`
- Finally filter data only to `616898 or 616901`

Note that if there is no matching data available for the given filter then you may not get the result. If you still want that data should be returned from `orders` table even if there is no match and joining table data as null you may need to change the `inner join` to `left join`

Comment: As I said you are filtering data for `616898, 616901` so check if the same order_id is on both `orders` and `orderProducts` if yes then check if the same `customer_id` for above order numbers are in both `orders` and `customers` if yes then check if there are some emails against those `customers` and if yes the above query will return data. But if any of the joining clause is failed in `inner join` then you will miss that record.